# Not equal condition not works Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I try to create custom finder in Repository class. And the where condition is find posts what created not by current user. But I still geting all posts. Here is the code:

```
public function selectRelatedTrips($assoc, $profileId)
{

    $params = array();
    $query = $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('t')
        ->from('VputiTripBundle:Trip', 't')
        ->where('t.profile != :profile');
    $params['profile']=$profileId;
    foreach ($assoc as $k => $v) {
        $query->orWhere('t.startCity = :param' . $k);
        $query->orWhere('t.targetCity = :param' . $k);
        $params['param' . $k] = $v;
    }

    return $query->setParameters($params)
        ->setMaxResults(20)
        ->orderBy('t.id', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `setParameter` correctly, too (ie: `->setParameter('profile', $theValue)`)?

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, I add entire function

Comment: Types of `t.profile` and `$profileId` are the same, right?

Comment: @devilcius, t.profile is relation to another entity, $profileId is id of related entity

Comment: then you should compare its identity with the id provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `t.profile` is an entity, you should compare like this:

```
->where('IDENTITY(t.profile) != :profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't compare to Id, you're mixing up id and entity this way. I prefer to compare the full entity, and delegate to the ORM the full comparison.

This is how I would correct your code, I would change just this line:

```
    $params['profile'] = $profile;
```